# apache phoenix multiple queryservers in connection string

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I am using HDP2.5 with HBase 1.1.2.2.5.3.0-37 and phoenix-4.7.0.2.5.3.0-37.

Both are up and running, able to create query hbase data from phoenix.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://hostname:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF");
```

In the above connection string, it is using only one query server address. But, I have multiple phoenix query servers up and running. I would like to use know how to specify multiple query server addresses in the string.

If I specify multiple query servers, am I going to get the fail-over mechanism.

For example: If some thing goes wrong with the current query server which is currently serving my request, is there a mechanism,which will redirect to the another query server which is running fine.

In the source code, it has only one `getConnectionUrl()` as below.

```
public static String getConnectionUrl(String protocol, String hostname, int port, String serialization) {
    String urlFmt = Driver.CONNECT_STRING_PREFIX + "url=%s://%s:%s;serialization=%s";
    return String.format(urlFmt, protocol, hostname, port, serialization);
}
```

Please let me know, how to use multiple query servers and how about failover mechanism.

Comment: I ended up using an nginx setup which load balances between the PQS servers

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mean, to achieve this, we need to setup nginx.`https://www.nginx.com/` . Is it free software?? If not is there any other way to achieve load balance in between PQS server?

Comment: the default nginx was fine from what I could tell.  it balanced based on ip more complex proxies can be built with the pay-for nginx, and apache http server